# Динамичное изменение данные в jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт:

```
function begin() {
    setInterval(function () {
        $.getJSON('какой-нибудь url' + $('#postId').val(), function (res) {
        }, 10000);
    });
}
```

И есть инпут форм:

```
<p:inputText id="postId" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px;"/>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при изменении текста в инпуте сразу же менялось значение в `begin();`.

Comment: не ASP.NET ли это?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input#postId').on('keyup', function () {
  $.getJSON('localhost:8080/get-json/' + $(this).val(), function (res) {});
});
```

Или

```
<p:inputText id="postId" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px;" onkeyup="begin($(this).val())" />
```

но в таком случае `begin()` должен принимать аргумент:

```
function begin(val){
   $.getJSON('localhost:8080/get-json/' + val, function (response){});
}
```